# Trying to get a task having delegate_to to show inventory alias instead of hostname in the output of a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a task in my playbook to take backups of a directory on each remote host itself, as :

```
- name: Copy files to backup
  synchronize:
    src: /opt/myDir/
    dest: /opt/myBackupDir/
    archive: yes
  ignore_errors: no
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  register: sync_out
```

And my inventory is like :

```
myWeb1   ansible_host=prodvm1  ansible_user=testuser
myApp1   ansible_host=prodvm2  ansible_user=testuser
myApp2   ansible_host=prodvm3  ansible_user=testuser
```

The issue is that the output shown is like below :

```
TASK [Copy files to backup] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myWeb1 -> prodvm1]
ok: [myApp1 -> prodvm2]
ok: [myApp2 -> prodvm3]
```

Since I am delegating the task there are two fields shown in the output, separated by the arrow mark, but I would like to have it show the name / alias specified in the inventory , i.e., myApp1/myWeb1 instead of the actual hostname ( prodvm* )  after the arrows ( to avoid showing the hostname / IPs ).

I tried to use debug module to see what ansible is evaulating *inventory_hostname* to , but it gives the expected result, i.e., myWeb1.

How can I get similar behaviour when using the delegate_to module ?

Answer (score 0):

It's really annoying behavior for Ansible. Delegation always 'cuts to the point' of where things happens.

If it's really annoy you, you can try disable delegation and use `ansible_host` trick, but at my opinion, delegation is better (even with junk in output).

This is the `ansible_host` trick:

```
- name: Copy files to backup
  synchronize:
    src: /opt/myDir/
    dest: /opt/myBackupDir/
    archive: true
  var:
    ansible_host: '{{ hostvars[name_where_its_delegated].ansible_host }}'
  register: sync_out
```

I warn you again, delegation is better than this.